# What does MPI Error 134 mean?

Tags: runtime-error, mpi, mpich

According to IBM, [error 134](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/clresctr/vxrx/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.cluster.pe.v1r3.pe300.doc%2F0032-139.htm) means that

> A Buffer is already attached in string, task number

and goes on to explain that

> An attempt was made to attach a buffer when a buffer was already attached.

which I find rather cryptic. Attempts to google the error message yielded no results.

In an attempt to isolate the error I commented out all MPI functions save for `MPI_Init` and `MPI_Finalize`. Specifically,

```
int main(...){
    MPI_Init(...);
    initialize();

    MPI_Barrier(MPI_COMM_WORLD);
    //do stuff, no synchronization at all
    MPI_Finalize();
    return 0;
}
```

`initialize()` reads some files and allocates memory. It also calls `MPI_Comm_rank` and `MPI_Comm_size` and stores it for later.

I am using MPICH2 version 1.4.1 (`1.4.1-1ubuntu1` according to dpkg) and compiling with gcc 4.6.3. The error occurs regardless of the number of processes started by mpiexec.

---

Edit: A quick search for the terms `134`, `error code` and `error message` on the [MPICH2 manual](http://www.mpich.org/static/downloads/3.0.4/mpich-3.0.4-userguide.pdf) did not provide any information. `mpiexec`'s manpage doesn't either.

---

Edit 2: The error in my program was solved after I realized I had a buffer overflow in `initialize()`. The question still stands though as I'd like to see a better explanation on this error.

Comment: Just some advice, I would refer to the [MPICH2](http://www.mpich.org/static/downloads/3.0.4/mpich-3.0.4-userguide.pdf) documentation and not the IBM documentation since they are two different implementations

Comment: @pyCthon I didn't realize, thank you for that